# Chrome Dev Tools ignores form re-submit warning?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I've just noticed, that I see Chrome browser's warning about resubmitting already submitted form only, when Chrome Dev Tools panel is closed. When it isopen -- no such warning is displayed.

Is this a bug or feature? And, if feature -- what is it purpose (I see none)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> while focused on the page it will ask me about a resubmit, but if I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> while focused on the dev tools panel it will reload without asking. This is using 36.0.1985.143 (haven't restarted Chrome since yesterday) in Windows.

If I click the reload button it always gives the warning (probably because it focuses on the main window).

Looking at the network tab, when I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> and it reloads without the resubmit warning it does post the same amount of information as if I had confirmed form resubmit.

This is likely done in order to test posting data within dev tools without having to constantly confirm resubmission. There have been [problems with form resubmission testing before](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/P7mAJOgUSXU) so I can see why they might have gone to lengths to make it easier. I guess they assume you are testing if you have dev tools open and you're pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> within dev tools.

If you are not seeing the warning while focused on the main window (with dev tools open) then maybe there is some bug for you, but I cannot reproduce this.